# How can I fade out a strip that requires an Alpha Under effect?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transparency

I have two strip with images and one effect strip.

- **Strip 0** has a standard JPG image that I set for the full length of the render.
- **Strip 1** is a PNG with alpha layer that contains text.
- **Strip 2** is an **Alpha Under** that is required so I can see **Strip 0** and **Strip 1** in the final render to video allowing the text to be rendered on top of the bottom strip.

[image]

My problem is I want to fade out **Strip 1** so the text fades away and does not effect **Strip 0**, unfortunately nothing I have tried works.

I tried:

1. Keyframing opacity on **Strip 1**: The opacity is changing but there
   is no effect on **Strip 1**. It does not fade away.
2. Keyframing opacity on **Strip 2**: This fades out all Strips
3. I tried making a Meta layer with all three strips and keyframing an opacity change. This would work if I added another strip of the same images as **Strip 0** but there is a darkening in the final render. This also required another Alpha Under strip. The end result is not clean.

[image]

How can I fade out a strip that requires an Alpha Under effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is:

1. Remove **Alpha under** effect strip
2. Set Image with text and alpha channel above *jpg*.
3. In <kbd>N</kbd>-menu set Blend type to **Alpha Over**.
4. Animate Opacity of text layer to create fade out effect

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I played with the Blend options but never in exactly as you outlined. I thought I was going a little crazy :P